# Dynamically sum cells whose neighboring cell contains certain text

Tags: excel

In my spreadsheet, I am tallying expenses made by John, Bob, and Simon for a project.

When John records an expense, it must contain his name (not case sensitive):

```
A                B

Apples(John)     50
```

Simon makes 90% of the expenses and doesn't always write his name down.

At the end of the project, an expense list might look like this:

```
  A                 B

  Apples(John)      50
  Toy (bob)         15
  Pencils John      30
  Metal             10
  Peaches (simon)   5  
  Donuts BOB        30
```

Without using macro's (which don't work on Android's Excel app), how can I dynamically sum their expenses as each new entry is entered?(I am logging expenses on the desktop and on the phone, synced through the cloud). I would like one cell for each team members total. This is tricky for me because I have to sum items in `B` if its corresponding entry in `A` contains a certain text. Something like:

```
Totals:

John         80
Simon        15
Bob          45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUMIF()` function will meet your requirement. You have to use `wildcard` in criteria part as names are mixed with item name. Try below formula.

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,"*" & D1 & "*",$B$1:$B$6)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for Simon's entries which may or may not be signed by him? I was thinking to just subtract bobs and John's totals from column B which would work, but maybe there is a more comprehensive solution? For example metal is considered Simon's expense

Comment: Then you have to use `Helper Column`. Helper column is an extra column where it will be decided that `metal` (item without having name) will be considered as `Simon` (next row user). Then calculate sum of expense.

Comment: @Harun24HR And to whom will you add expenses if it's called ```Bobcat (simon)```?

Comment: @basic If the situation is os, then have to extract names first then have to sum. His example does not have those types of data. Then have to think some other formula,

Comment: I won't have data like Bobcat, but I'm confused on this Helper Column. Can you explain this further?